# What version have I installed

Tags: versions

I read that MB-Lab 1.7.5 requires Blender 2.80.74 or later. I cannot find what my exact version is, it just says 2.80.

Answer (score 11):

### Blender 2.9x

There are four locations that show the version in varying level of detail.

**Splash screen**

[image: Blender Icon > Splash Screen]

[image: Splash screen of a development build]

**Status Bar**

[image: Status bar]

**About Blender**

[image: Blender Icon > About Blender]

[image: About pop-up]

**Export System Information**

[image: Help > Save System Info]

```
===========================================
= Blender 2.91.0 Alpha System Information =
===========================================


Blender:
===========================================

version: 2.91.0 Alpha, branch: master, commit date: 2020-08-06 17:52, hash: 9a1ff4445b98, type: 
build date: 2020-08-06, 21:59:05
```

---

### Blender 2.8x

There are three locations that show the version in varying level of detail.

**Splash screen with the name of the release**

[image: Show splash screen]

### [image: Splash screen]

**Status bar with the version number**

[image: Status bar]

---

***Help > Save System Info* detailed information including the commit hash**

[image: Save system info]

Excerpt from the system-info.txt

```
============================================
= Blender 2.80 (sub 75) System Information =
============================================


Blender:
============================================

version: 2.80 (sub 75), branch: master, commit date: 2019-07-29 14:47, hash: f6cb5f54494e, type: 
build date: 2019-07-29, 09:44 AM
```

Comment: In the process of modernizing Blender UI, this could be moved to the help menu, a common choice for Windows applications.

Answer (score 2):

Stasus bar at bottom must show it in far right if you dont see it all scroll it.
If not go to help menu: **save system info**, version must be at the beginning of file.
For me it 2.80 (sub 75) which means 2.80.75