# Blender 2.8 How do I find out which version and build I am using?

Tags: versions

How do I find out which version and build I am using? Normally this is in "About" under the Help, but not in Blender.

Comment: This question has been asked before: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/148129/what-version-have-i-installed/148133#148133

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either go to the *Blender* menu on the top left and open the *Splash Screen* entry,

[image]

[image]

or go to *Help > Save System Info*, browse your file system and save the file. Upon opening it with any text editor it will reveal your complete system info, including build version.

[image]

[image]